# kubectl logs - continuously

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

```
kubectl logs <pod-id>
```

gets latest logs from my deployment - I am working on a bug and interested to know the logs at runtime - How can I get continuous stream of logs ?

edit: corrected question at the end.

Answer (score 363, accepted):

```
kubectl logs -f <pod-id>
```

You can use the `-f` flag:

`-f, --follow=false: Specify if the logs should be streamed.`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs

Comment: what about logs for service or anything other than the pods?

Comment: this works for a short time then the logs stop. I have to ctrl-c to get out of kubectl, then restart them. This shows more logs after but stops again. Anyone know why the logs stop in random spots when they are obviously still being generated by the pod?

Comment: @pferrel, did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Could be related to log rotation: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59902

Comment: @duyn9uyen I think it's because logs stop coming in from the server. even without restarting kubectl, logs start coming in automatically

Comment: I'm facing similar issues. I have tried kubectl attach (mentioned in answer below). but occasionally the logs stop there as well.

Answer (score 36):

`kubectl logs --help` will guide you:

Example:

```
# Begin streaming the logs of the ruby container in pod web-1
kubectl logs -f -c ruby web-1
```

Flags:

```
-f, --follow[=false]: Specify if the logs should be streamed.
```

You can also add `--since=10m` or so start from that relative time ago.

Comment: can there be more than one container in a pod?

Comment: @AlexanderMills yes, this is the ["sidecar" pattern](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine)

Answer (score 32):

I needed to access the logs of a long running pod, and `-f` began streaming logs from days ago, which would have taken hours to get to where I needed to view ( just the last couple minutes or so ).

There is a `--since=10m` flag, but that didn't seem to work for me.

What did wonders was `--tail=100`, where `100` is the number of recent lines to display.

Comment: Combining the two was the best for me: `--tail=100 -f` started 100 lines ago but also started streaming in realtime

Answer (score 16):

Putting it all together, you likely won't want to see all of the old history, so to see only the 20 most recent lines and continue to add new lines of (i.e. follow) the output, run it like so:

```
kubectl logs --tail=20 -f container-name
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this,

**tail logs from pods**

kubectl --tail <"no of lines"> logs <"pod_name">

**Example** :

kubectl --tail 100 logs app_pod

Answer (score 10):

If you want to get the stream of logs from a multi pod app you can use [kubetail](https://github.com/johanhaleby/kubetail), example:

```
kubectl get pods

NAME                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
app2-v31-9pbpn         1/1       Running   0          1d
app2-v31-q74wg         1/1       Running   0          1d

kubetail app2
```

With that command, kubetail is *tailing* the logs from pod *app2-v31-9pbpn* **and** *app2-v31-q74wg*

Answer (score 6):

You can follow logs with -f

```
kubectl logs -f <pod_name>
```

If logs are stopped most probably the pod is crashing, can you check if pod is actually running or not? Check age maybe or :

```
kubectl describe deploy/ds <deploy_or_ds_name>?
```

Or you can also check the logs for container inside pod in there are multiple containers

```
kubectl logs -f <pod_name> -c <container_name>
```

Answer (score 4):

## wait for kubes to spin up pod then move on...

```
k8s_pod=some_pod
kubectl get pods -w $k8s_pod | while read LOGLINE
do
   [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Running"* ]] && pkill -P $$ kubectl
done
```

## tail logs

```
for line in $(kubectl get pods | grep $k8s_pod | awk '{print $1}'); do
    kubectl logs -f $line | tee logfile
done
```

## look for success indicator

```
tail logfile | grep successful! 
RESULT=$?
exit $RESULT
```

Comment: 'successful!' may need to change depending on your pod.

Comment: I took those first two parts from several other stackoverflow posts so I can't take credit for those entirely but the combo I hope will serve others well...

Answer (score 4):

`kubectl logs -f zk-app-0 --tail 10`

This command will stream logs starting from last 10 lines. If tail is not mentioned here, k8s will stream all the available logs (i.e. last 10 MB of logs or last 5 log rotations).

However sometimes I have faced issues with this command where the log streaming stops. Then I just press ctrl-c and run the command again.

Another way to stream stdout and stderr from the process in the container is to use kubectl attach.

```
kubectl attach zk-app-0
```

This will attach to the main container and stream the console logs. however this will not have any additional logging features present in kubectl logs. In this case if the logging stops simply hit enter in the keyboard and it should resume.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get logs from the specific namespace, you can use either one command,

```
kubectl logs -n <NAMESPACE> -f <POD_NAME> -c <CONTAINER_NAME>
```

or

```
kubectl logs -n <NAMESPACE> -p <POD_NAME> -c <CONTAINER_NAME> --previous=false
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Suggestion

It seems that you wish to view logs from your terminal without using a "heavy" 3rd party logging solution.

For that I would consider using [K9S](https://github.com/derailed/k9s) which is a great CLI tool that help you get control over your cluster - view the different k8s resources, navigate between workloads and dive deep into logs and watch them continuously.

---

#### How to use the tool (in a few lines)

After setting up the K8S context in the current terminal you just enter `k9s` to hit the dashboard. From there, you can type the resource (service,deployment,pod..) you wish to view by typing `":"` - and the resource name.

You can also start at the namespace level and go all the way down to the pods and containers logs - as can be seen in the example below:

[image]

---

#### Alternatives

If you are not bound only to the CLI but still want run locally I would recommend on [Lens](https://k8slens.dev/).

Answer (score 1):

> > kubctl logs -f=true [pod-name] -c [container-name]

If you just have a single container over the pod, container name is not necessary else use the container name with -c option.
-f i.e. follow is false by default. If you do not set it to true you will get a snapshot of your container logs.

Answer (score 1):

There's two things I'd like to add to the other suggestions already made here:

1. You can use the `-l` flag to tail logs for pods by label instead of fetching the individual pod name: `kubectl logs -f -l app=cwagent-prometheus -n amazon-cloudwatch`.  This command will still die if there are no matching pods.
2. You can use something like [overmind](https://github.com/DarthSim/overmind) or [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to put together a `Procfile` of log commands to run:

```
cloudwatch: kubectl logs -f -l app=cwagent-prometheus -n amazon-cloudwatch
egress: kubectl logs -f -l istio=egressgateway -n istio-ingress
extauth: kubectl logs -f -l context=api-gateway -n istio-ingress
external-dns: kubectl logs -f -l app=external-dns -n external-dns
ingress: kubectl logs -f -l istio=ingressgateway -n istio-ingress
istiod: kubectl logs -f -l app=istiod -n istio-system
ratelimit: kubectl logs -f -l app=ratelimit -n istio-ingress
redis: kubectl logs -f -l app.kubernetes.io/name=redis -n istio-ingress
```

With this `Procfile` you can get a color-coded, aggregated view of the log output (colors not shown here):

```sh
$ OVERMIND_AUTO_RESTART=cloudwatch,external-dns,ingress,egress,extauth,ratelimit,istiod,redis \
  overmind s \
  -f Procfile-logs
system       | Tmux socket name: overmind-api-gateway-1mvHWIKJ47dOFnOZVLfWuO
system       | Tmux session ID: api-gateway
system       | Listening at ./.overmind.sock
ratelimit    | Started with pid 57088...
istiod       | Started with pid 57074...
ingress      | Started with pid 57061...
egress       | Started with pid 57036...
cloudwatch   | Started with pid 57031...
external-dns | Started with pid 57051...
redis        | Started with pid 57095...
extauth      | Started with pid 57041...
```

You can put this command in a `Makefile` so that you just run something like this:

```sh
$ make logs
```

The `OVERMIND_AUTO_RESTART` in this example causes `overmind` to restart the command if all the pods go away.

Answer (score 0):

Aah, an alternative answer is a way to watch anything:

```
watch -c [insert any command]
```

for example `watch -c kubectl get all -n coolapp`

or

`watch -c ps aux`